# sql query with laravel with join (2 tables)

Tags: sql, laravel

Bonjour,

I would like to create an SQL query for my Laravel project.
To explain you a little bit my 2 tables.

I have a "products" table.
In this table, I have a primary key > products_id.
I also have a "status" column that specifies if the products_id is "for sale" or "for rent".

I have a second table "products_criteres".
In this table, the primary key is > products_id
I have a "criteres_id" column that must be = "30".

So I would like to get all the products_id that are = "30" in the "products_criteres" table and the "status" column to be equal to "for sale" in the "products" table.

I tried something like this, but nothing works:

```
SELECT products_main_criteres_history.products_id,date,criteres_id
FROM products_main_criteres_history LEFT JOIN products ON products_main_criteres_history.products_id = products_id
WHERE products_main_criteres_history.criteres_id = 30 
WHERE products.status = "a vendre"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Use this function query callback function*

```
$products_sql = products::where('status','for sale')
                         ->whereIn('products_id',function($q){
                           $q->select('products_id')->from('products_criteres')
                         ->where('criteres_id',30)})->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

example

$products_sql = products::join('products_details', 'products.id', '=', 'products_details.id')
->where('products.quality', 'good')
->get();

I understood how you wanted to relate the tables but it’s something like this
create the variable calls the table relating the tables and make a 'where' with table.column and put the vaslor that you only want the result to have

Answer (score 0):

```
products::where('status','for sale')
->whereIn('products_id',function($query){
   $query->select('products_id')->from('products_criteres')
         ->where('criteres_id',30)
})->get()
```

Answer (score 0):

this code returns `products` with `criteres` that have `products_id = 30` and `state = "for sale"` :

```
SELECT pr.id,pr.date,prc.*
FROM products pr inner JOIN products_criteres prc ON pr.id = prc.products_id 
WHERE pr.products_id  = 30 
and pr.status = "for sale"
```